# Editar arquivo doc através do C#

Tags: c#, arquivo, impressão

Tenho um programa que gera códigos de barras, insere-os em um arquivo .txt e imprime esse aquivo. O que eu quero é que esses códigos de barras sejam inseridos num arquivo `doc` com um template do papel da etiqueta (no caso são etiquetas Pimaco tamanho 6287) para que, na hora da impressão, os códigos saiam certo na etiqueta. Caso contrário terei que usar uma folha lisa de etiqueta e depois ir cortando cada uma.

Comment: Já pensou em criar um plugin pro word?

Comment: Você quer fazer [algo assim](http://www.dotnethub.org/?p=4)?

Comment: Na verdade não e não imagino como criar isso. Tenho urgência com esse  programa pois tenho que etiquetar 1000 componentes eletrônicos até sábado.

Comment: Isso @CiganoMorrisonMendez só que com um template pronto no Word. Aquele de etiqueta.

Comment: Acho que vai dar mais trabalho. Era melhor fazer direto no C# e ir alinhando a etiqueta usando testes com papel A4.

Comment: Nesse exemplo não é possível colocar os tamanhos exatos e mandar escrever?

Comment: Dá sim. Usando os eixos `x` e `y`, mas isso requer montar o exemplo, imprimir no A4 e ver como sai, e depois realizar os ajustes.

Comment: Sim entendi, vou tentar. Obrigada!